# My js does not work on html of dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, guys. I am new to js and I have a problem, it seems that my html does not call my js. I dont know if I´ve place it on a wrong line or what causes that, but I´ve all ready checked my code on http://validator.w3.org/nu and it seems right. My html is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>hola</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="menuscrollfixed.js"></script>
<link href="scrollfixedmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="texte/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="nav-container">
<div class="nav">

<ul> 
    <li><a href="" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF; font-family: Josefin Sans;">NOSOTROS</a></li>
    <li><a href="" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF; font-family: Josefin Sans;">VISIÓN</a></li>
    <li><a href="" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF; font-family: Josefin Sans;">MISIÓN</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Js:

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($) {
var nav = $(".nav container");
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrolltop() > 400) {
        nav.addClass("f-nav");
    } else {
        nav.removeClass("f-nav");
    }
});
});
```

I know it´s a bit long, but I really hope someone can help me =)

Comment: hi i think you mistake this var nav = $(".nav container"); into this var nav = $(".nav-container");

Comment: Please check you var nav

Comment: `type="texte/javascript"` for second jq lib seriously??

Answer (score 0):

You need to rearrange the order of script references. Refer jquery before your custom js file.

```
<link href="scrollfixedmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="texte/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="menuscrollfixed.js"></script>
```

Because, you are using jquery functions inside your custom js file. At the time of executing those codes, the jquery file will not be loaded, which will cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things i noticed in your page:

1. Re-arrange the stack order of your scripts. add jQ lib before your script file.
2. use only one jQ lib instead of two diff versions.
3. `type="texte/javascript"` is not a valid type.
4. Better to use `jQuery(document)` instead of `jQuery("document")`.
5. `$(".nav container");` there is no element of named `container` in `.nav` and i don't think it's a valid html element *container*.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you are using multiple versions of Jquery Library files. This we create conflicts while using the features. Use the latest version.

And keep an eye on the wrong spelling for scripts and calling class names.